# Get Google email address with OAuth2 bearer token without deprecated Google+ APIs

Tags: email, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I've been using the `plus.people.get` Google method with an OAuth2 bearer token in order to fetch the user's email address after an OAuth2 login. That endpoint will be [shut down](https://developers.google.com/+/api-shutdown) in March, with 'intermittent errors' starting at the end of January.

I can't seem to find an equivalent endpoint that allows me to exchange an OAuth2 token for the user's email address with no, or minimal, additional scope. All the (numerous) answers I've come across on SO are out of date due to the deprecation, there's no replacement APIs listed in the shutdown announcement, and so far I've not found a functionally equivalent Google API.

The Gmail [profile API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/getProfile) will allow email retrieval, but the minimal scope allows reading the user's email. I don't want to require my users to have to approve that for obvious reasons.

Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I'm unable to find anything helpful so far.

EDIT: of course directly after posting I found the [people API.](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get)

Comment: You should be able to get the email after sign in, how are you doing OAuth2 login?

Comment: As @John Hanley said "The current list of OAuth endpoints can be downloaded https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration". As described at https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#discovery

Answer (score 0):

Authorize the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` and call the Google OAuth2 API endpoint (oauth2 v2) `userinfo.v2.me.get` if you are using a library or directly to `https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me` with the authentication.